# Coordinate Representation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $B = \left\{1, 1 + x, 1 + x + x^2\right\}$, a basis for $P_2$.

(a) Find the element of $P_2$ corresponding to the coordinate vector 
$\mathbf{u}_B = \left\{\left\{1\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{-2\right\}\right\}$

(b) Find the coordinate representation $\mathbf{v}_B$ for the vector $\mathbf{v} = 3 − x − x^2$

(c) Find a matrix representation, with respect to the basis B, of the linear transformation defined as:

$$T(a + bx + cx^2) = a + c + bx^2$$

I believe I was able to find (b) for this problem so far. By writing $\mathbf{v}$ in terms of the basis $B$, I solved for the coordinate representation $\mathbf{v}_B = \{\{4\},\{0\},\{-1\}\}$

Not sure where to start with (a) and (c).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For (a), we have $\mathbf{u}_B= 1\cdot (1)+3\cdot(1+x)-2\cdot(1+x+x^2)=....$

For (b) your answer is correct.

For (c), note that 
$$\mathbf{v}=a+bx+cx^2=(a-b)\cdot (1)+(b-c)\cdot(1+x)+c(1+x+x^2)
$$ and
$$
\mathbf{u}=a+c+bx^2=(a+c)\cdot(1)-b\cdot(1+x)+b\cdot (1+x+x^2)
$$

so $\mathbf{v}_B=[a-b,b-c,c]^T$, and $\mathbf{u}_B=[a+c,-b,b]^T$

now you can find the matrix that represents the transformation
$$
T\left([a-b,b-c,c]^T \right)=[a+c,-b,b]^T
$$
by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find the matrix $M_B$ that represents the change of basis from $B$ to the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ (it can be found by inspection—remember what the columns of a linear transformation matrix are). The first two parts of the problem can then be solved by multiplying a column vector by $B$ or its inverse, as appropriate. The third part is solved by applying the change-of-basis formula to the matrix for $T$ relative to the standard basis (which can also be written down by inspection).